# How to save data for user log in/ register using a hashtable?

Tags: c, file, hashtable

I am trying to make a log-in/ register function for a game in C language using a client and server. The user should able to register, login and the hash table will be able to know what user name is taken or if a password is incorrect. I think my code works but when the program is ended the hash table resets again which makes it pointless. Is there a way to have the usernames and passwords saved so it doesn't reset using the code I have already made?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// hash function
int hashFunction(const char* username){
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(username); i++){
        result = (13*result + username[i]) % 3119;
    }
    return result;
}

void login_register(int mode, char* username, char* password, char hashTable[][21]){
    if(mode == 1) { // register mode will be 1
        char new_username[21];
        while(1){
            printf("Enter a username.\n");
            scanf("%s", new_username);
            // check for duplicate here
            int hashResult = hashFunction(new_username);
            if(strcmp(hashTable[hashResult%128], ".") == 0){
                strcpy(username, new_username);
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Username is taken try again.\n");
            }
        }
        char new_password[21];
        printf("Enter a password.\n");
        scanf("%s", new_password);
        // copy over the newly input values into the parameters
        strcpy(password, new_password);
    }
    
    else{
        char new_username[21];
        char new_password[21];
        printf("Enter your username.\n");
        scanf("%s", new_username);
        strcpy(username, new_username);
        
        while(1){
            printf("Enter your password.\n");
            scanf("%s", new_password);
            strcpy(password, new_password);
            // check for duplicate here
            int hashResult = hashFunction(new_username);
            if(strcmp(hashTable[hashResult%128], password ) == 0){
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("Password is incorrect try again.\n");
            }
        }
        
    }
        
}



int main()
{
    char hashTable[128][21];
    // 128 total strings in the array
    //each string will be 20 chars long plus the '\0' at the end of each string
    for(int i = 0; i < 128; i++){
        strcpy(hashTable[i], "."); // we initialize each index of the hash table to just have a default value so we have something to compare against
    }
    int mode = 1;
    char username[21]; // variable to hold the username
    char password[21]; // variable to hold the password
    //strcpy(hashTable[35], "password"); // this was just me testing ignore that
    login_register(mode, username, password, hashTable);
    printf("%s\n", username);
    printf("%s\n", password);
    
}
```

Comment: You have to use persistent storage such as a file or database. The specifics of how to do that is too broad for this question. Start by researching how to read/write data from/to a file.

Comment: Well clearly if you want to store data in between runs you save something to disk.

Comment: BTW: As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, read the description of the tags that you applied, one of them is wrong! You can [edit] your question in order to fix that.

Comment: Tip: For hash tables *do not* use sizing numbers with a lot of factors. Use primes for sizes.